# Create custom DarkMode Toggle button with PHP Function and CSS in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, darkmode

I Wrote a mini function plugin with PHP and CSS but not work correctly at whole site, work just text in body content section. but I need complete DarkMode button system!
I know that if changes are made in the code I wrote it will work correctly but I don't know what to change to make it correct.

function (theme function.php):

```
function dark_mode_toggle() {
    ?>
    <button id="dark-mode-toggle">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'dark_mode_toggle' );
```

css:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

a,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #0074a2;
}

#dark-mode-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.dark-mode {
    background-color: #333 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.dark-mode a,
.dark-mode a:visited,
.dark-mode a:hover,
.dark-mode a:active {
    color: #0074a2;
}

.dark-mode h1,
.dark-mode h2,
.dark-mode h3,
.dark-mode h4,
.dark-mode h5,
.dark-mode h6 {
    color: #fff;
}

.dark-mode button,
.dark-mode input[type="button"],
.dark-mode input[type="reset"],
.dark-mode input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #0074a2;
    color: #fff;
}
```

PHP for footer.php:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('dark-mode-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the piece of code that you called "PHP for footer.php:" is `Javascript`, not `PHP`. Anyway there you go, you can customise this code :

PHP

```
function dark_mode_toggle() {
    echo '<button id="dark-mode-toggle">Toggle Dark Mode</button>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'dark_mode_toggle' );
```

CSS

```
<style>
    #dark-mode-toggle {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    body.dark-mode {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
    }
a,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #0074a2;
}

a.dark-mode,
a:visited.dark-mode,
a:hover.dark-mode,
a:active.dark-mode {
    color: #0074a2;
}

h1.dark-mode,
h2.dark-mode,
h3.dark-mode,
h4.dark-mode,
h5.dark-mode,
h6.dark-mode {
    color: #fff;
}

button.dark-mode,
input[type="button"].dark-mode,
input[type="reset"].dark-mode,
input[type="submit"].dark-mode {
    background-color: #0074a2;
    color: #fff;
}

.dark-mode {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

JS

```
<script>
    const toggleBtn = document.getElementById("dark-mode-toggle");
    toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: HTML : <button id="dark-mode-toggle">Toggle Dark Mode</button>

Comment: thank you but this code only change body texts in my container and dont change everything like buttons color, backgrounds and more... this code like working my first code.

Comment: @ahmadwp as you can see i wrote "you can customise this code" meaning, do it yourself. First of all you must put this code at the end of your css file. It MUST be the last css your server can read, because if it is last, then it can overlaps the previous css code in your file.

Comment: Don't use !important, it's useless and can cause conflits within your code. Just put the code you want to execute over the other code at the end of the file.

Comment: It suggest you to read the css documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference or to follow a css course with only basics. So you'll know how to debug it next time :)

Comment: Btw I edited my code, so it should do the thing you want. And as you can see, we write the html tag first, then we add the class just like this : "h1 .dark-mode"